# Cable lock with Mac Mini

Tags: security, mac-mini

How do I use a cable lock with my Mac Mini? It doesn't appear to have any mounts for the typical cable lock. Do I have to get an enclosure and secure that to the desk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need an enclosure to use a Kensington lock. 
As you can see Mac Mini doesn't have a pin lock. 
[image: Mac Mini rear]